# position sticky doesnt apply to flex child though i use top

Tags: html, css, flexbox, sticky, sidenav

im trying to build a ui with html.

1. The navbar should stay at the top
2. Some video below the navbar and the other content should scroll on the video( for now it is brown box) .
3. The sky blue box(which is for side navigation) should stop right below the nav box and pink box(content box) should continue scrolling.

issues :

1. the sticky nav box scrolls up after some scrolling and
2. the sky blue box doesn't stop below nav box. 
   please see the codepen and help me out....
   html

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  top: 400px;
  border-top: 4px solid black;
}

.box1 {
  /* height:500px; */
  position: sticky;
  top: 50px;
  width: 40%;
  background-color: aqua;
  border: 2px solid grey;
}

.box2 {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 60%;
  background-color: pink;
}

.nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 1000;
  height: 50px;
}

.image-con {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: brown;
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1000;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav"></div>

<div class="image-con"></div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/mbs-yaswanth/pen/yZOLXQ

Comment: Which browser are you testing the above code on? The `sticky` property still has a lot of browser compatibility issues right now.

Comment: chrome  browser - Version 72.0.3626.64 (Official Build) beta (64-bit)

Comment: Weird. It should be working fine on Chrome v72.

Comment: yeah, thats what. i feel like there is someting with the flexbox. please see the codepen..

Comment: Is the nav always going to be at the top? Is there a reason why you would not just use a fixed position?

Comment: I figured out why it is scrolling back up the page (see answer below) but if you do not have content above the nav to scroll though before the nav hits the top of the page position fixed may be a better option due to browser compatibility as @AndrewL64 stated earlier

Answer (score 2):

Remove

```
body,html{
        height: 100%;
}
```

Once your sticky nav is hitting the bottom of your html and body it is not sticky anymore. It seems to move back up the page but its really just not following you through the overflow.  Hope this helps.
**EDIT**
I think this is what you are looking for I changed a good bit of your code so just review it carefully.  for some reason when you run the snippet box 2 gets smaller but it works in full page preview. Hope this helps

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.box1 {
  height:500px; 
  position: sticky;
  top: 50px;
  width: 39%;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: aqua;
  border: 2px solid grey;
}

.box2 {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1000px;
  width: 60%;
  background-color: pink;
}

.nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 50px;
}

.image-con {
  background-color: brown;
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav"></div>

<div class="image-con"></div>

<div class="box1"></div>

<div class="box2"></div>
```

Comment: Cool! Thank you this is working but still why the '.box1' still doesn't stick? @kjek-code

Comment: More thank likely it is because box1 is inside of container and the container is not sticky. All sticky does is toggle between position fixed and position relative so if a parent element is still relative it probably won't work correctly. Try sticky on container not box1

Comment: I edited the above answer. I was kind of right in my comment above that does work but does not give you what you asked for in your question.  The above answer should give you what you want.  Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: yeah, this is working and you forgot to fix the '.image-con' . I'm afraid that there will be some white space below box1 since both boxes are not of same height. if i use flex, then it expands to the height of box2. And i recently reliazed that i need a box below these two boxes for footer. anyway thanks for  helping me.